# What part of speech is "talking" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm confused as to the part of speech the word "talking" belongs to in the following sentence.

"Paula felt much calmer after talking to her grandmother."

Is it a verb or a gerund or something else?

Comment: After a preposition such as after the ing-form is a gerund , which has verbal and noun character.

Answer (score 2):

In the example

> "Paula felt much calmer after talking to her grandmother."

"talking" is a gerund.  Gerunds are verbs within their own constituents, i.e., "downstairs", but they are nouns "upstairs", since they are heads of a noun phrase.  Here, "talking" is a verb taking "to her grandmother" as complement.  You can tell it's a verb from the absence of a preceding article ("a talking ...") and from the fact that it could be modified by an adverb, e.g., "quickly talking to her grandmother".  If "talking" were a noun, it could only be modified by an adjective, not an adverb (as in "a quick talking").

However, looking upstairs at what part "talking to her grandmother" plays in the entire construction, evidently this phrase is the object of the preposition "after".  A simple noun phrase could stand in this position: "Paula felt much calmer after lunch."  So, since the head of a noun phrase is a noun, we can identify "talking" as an upstairs noun.  "Talking to her grandmother" is a nominalization of a sentence "she talked to her grandmother".  That is why we could also have a perfect tense here, because it is a logical past tense, and past tenses get shifted to perfects in non-finite verbs: "Paula felt much calmer after having talked to her grandmother."

Such cases where there is a mismatch between the upstairs part of speech and the downstairs part of speech are generally puzzling for traditional grammarians, because they think of the part of speech as being an inherent property of a word.

Gerunds are upstairs nouns but downstairs verbs.  Participles are upstairs adjectives but downstairs verbs.

Comment: "Upstairs" tells us about the function, "downstairs" is what it's made of.

Comment: Well, but when you say "what it's made of", what's the "it"?  Here, the "it" is the sentence "She talked to her grandmother" (the "it" is not "talking").  This is why I prefer "upstairs/downstairs" to McCawley's terms "external/internal".  When you're downstairs, you can look around and see other stuff on the same floor.

Comment: 'After' is still a subordinate conjunction in the sentence.  It is only a preposition when it means 'next in line'.

Comment: @AmI, Do you have evidence from English for this?  Or are you just repeating something someone else once said or wrote?

Comment: Do people explain downvotes here on English SE?

Comment: @Brian Tung  They should.  In this case, I suspect the downvoter's poor little brain hurt after the first few sentences, and he took his revenge.

Answer (score 1):

"+ ing" construction of verbs is required to make: 1) present participle, 2) gerund and 3) verbal noun.
Present participles are used in formation of tenses conveying tense oriented sense only. When used alone, present participles embody the qualities of both verb and adjective.

Gerund is a verbal noun (+ing form) may be used as a subject or object of a verb or object to a preposition. We call '-ing' form verbal noun if preceded by ' the' and followed by 'of' and the sense it embibes is predominantly noun- like. So all verbal nouns are not gerund.

In the instant example, "talking" is a gerund being object of the preposition "after". As 'talking' is born out of verb it takes 'to' and all that follows.

Answer (score 0):

It is a verb participle.  The un-elided version near 'talking' is: ...'after [she] [was] talking'...  The subject of the conjuncted clause can be assumed [Paula], and the verb [be], and the tense [did] {from felt = did feel}.  // That answer got too many comments, so I'll add: 'talking' appeared without an auxiliary verb, so it looks like a gerund, but a gerund is not an action; it is the concept of the action.  English tries to avoid multiple morphemes on a word, so the progressive becomes a verb by adding a form of 'be'.  Any verb becomes a concept by adding the infinitive marker 'to'.  The sentence in question did not mean ...'after [to be] talking'...

Comment: Except that *Paula felt much calmer after she was talking to her grandmother* sounds nonsensical. I've always taken it to be a gerund, being the object of the preposition *after*. A participial construction would be *Paula felt much calmer, having talked to her grandmother.*

Comment: @Anonym In trad gram, "talking" would be considered a gerund on the grounds that it is complement to the prep "after". But that ignores the fact that "talking" is clearly functioning as a verb here, as demonstrated by its ability to take an NP complement as in "talking nonsense". Nouns don't take objects!  CGEL doesn't distinguish between the two uses, and simply calls the -ing forms gerund-participles.

Comment: @BillJ A gerund is a form which acts *simultaneously* as a verb and a noun, just as a participle is a form which acts simultaneously as a verb and as an adjective.

Comment: @StoneyB But surely a word can't belong to two parts of speech at the same time? And how is "talking" in "after talking to her grandmother" behaving 'simultaneously' like a noun?

Comment: @BillJ A gerund is a noun derived from and displaying the characteristics of a verb and a participle is an adjective derived from and displaying the characteristics of a verb. Both gerunds and participles can take objects.

Comment: We've looked at Aarts' overview of the _ing_-forms on the noun - verb continuum-or-is-it before. He says that grammarians fall into 3 camps: (a) those who say all such individual usages can be labelled as either N or V, depending on which prototype they are closer to (though this itself can cause arguments); (b) those who say that some individual usages may be both noun and verb at the same time; (c) those who say that some  usages are on a N - V gradience, and are intermediate between noun and verb. Forced perhaps arbitrarily into a class, in two classes at the same time, or in neither class.

Comment: @Anonym Actually, trad gram defines a gerund as a verb-form that is functionally similar to a noun. No matter, modern grammar simply treats the -ing form as a verb in, for example, "He was expelled for killing the birds" and as a noun in "She had witnessed the killing of the birds". And in "They are entertaining the audience" as a verb, and "The show seemed entertaining" as an adjective.

Comment: @Anonym Note also that an example such as  "I like smoking" is strictly speaking ambiguous, but the verb is the more salient interpretation (“I like to smoke”). Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "occasional smoking". Likewise "Smoking is harmful" or "smoking in the pub is not permitted" (cf, Even occasional social smoking in the pub is prohibited)

Comment: @BillJ Why can't a word belong to two parts of speech at the same time?  "Talking" (in the traditional analysis) is at once a noun as the object of *after* and a verb as the predicator of the clause *[she] talking to her grandmother*. "Salience", which you admit in your last comment, is scalar, not binary.

Comment: @StoneyB But "talking to her grandmother" is not the object of "after" (an object of "after" would be something like "after lunch"). It's a subordinate clause functioning as complement, not object.

Comment: @BillJ I think most modern linguists follow *CGEL* in regarding the traditional distinction between prepositions and most "subordinating conjunctions" as artificial.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't follow you. All I'm saying is that "talking to her grandmother" is not the object of "after" in the same way that the NP "a rest" would be in "after a rest". That's the difference between trad grammar and, say CGEL, the former analysing "talking" as a gerund, and the latter as a verb heading a gerund-participial clause. Note that "talking" can take an adverb like "candidly" - cf, "after talking candidly to her grandmother". Only a verb could do that.

Comment: @BillJ  Gerunds slide along a verby-nouny scale. 1) "He napped after dinner." "He napped after dining." He napped after dining on snails." 2) "Her talking disturbs me." "Her loud talking disturbs me." "Her talking loudly disturbs me."

Comment: So there is no universally accepted answer to this seemingly straightforward question? No wonder my head hurts. :-)

Comment: @StoneyB Do you mean a gerund is a verb doing the same function that we often expect from a noun? Because obviously it's a verb functioning as a verb :D Because verbs can function like that :D

Comment: @StoneyB ' "Talking" (in the traditional analysis) is at once a noun as the object of after and a verb as the predicator of the clause [she] talking to her grandmother'. <---  The problem with that is that it confuses functions ['Object of a prep' and 'Predicator'] with parts of speech. However, we do not need that 'dual function' anyhow. The *clause* is the Complement of the preposition and the *verb* is the Predicator in the clause.

Comment: @Araucaria By and large I agree that it's better to take the clause rather than the verb as the thing-which-follows-the-preposition, and I don't much care whether you call it an Object or a Complement or an Oblique. But there are situations when the verbform in *-ing* is almost wholly nounified: "I was annoyed by his loud talking" vs "I was annoyed by him talking loudly".

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, but that's a fully fledged noun. There are some properly intermediate sentences around, but they're all of pretty marginal acceptability, and they are very, very rare. [This is my take on gerund-participals versus nouns](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73272/why-is-his-driving-the-car-wrong/73325#73325). It happily ignores those very,  very  rare marginal sentences.

Comment: @StoneyB One example of a truly indeterminate sentence from CaGEL "*This constant telling tales has got to stop*". They say simply that "*The examples ... illustrate the kind of hybrid construction that can arise when a  historical change has not been carried through to completion. Such examples resist elegant description*". It may be therefore that in cases like that we could genuinely consider the word *telling* as a hybrid between a noun and a verb ...?

Comment: @Araucaria So at what point does it cross the line from verb to "fully-fledged" noun? What's the feather? A determiner? (*This bickering annoys me*) A possessive (hence determinative) Subject? (*John's bickering annoys me*). An adjectival adjunct? (*Constant bickering annoys me*). I don't think there's a bright line.

Comment: @StoneyB No, as H&P concede there is no bright line. H&P would regard a genetive pronoun as an NP in Determiner function. From their point of view having a true determinative would count as making the *-ing* form a noun. So would having adjectival modification. Contrastingly, having an adverb as a modifier or having a direct object would definitely count towards being a verb. Of course those very rare sentences such as the one above don't fit into either category. They are very rare, but they are still problematic. Notice that we don't seem to be able to just make those up ...

Comment: @StoneyB ... IMO, the reason that the example above is  marginally acceptable is that *telling tales* is a kind of idiom. I have a feeling that the speaker has kind of used a verb [telling tales] as a base from which to morphologically form a noun. They aren't treating *tales* as a direct object of *telling*. But that's just my theory. At the end of the day, as you say there isn't a clear bright line - unless you accept hybrids (in which case certain features would definitely count a word *in*, I suppose).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32722/discussion-on-answer-by-ami-what-part-of-speech-is-talking-in-the-following-se).

Comment: A gerund is most similar to an infinitive: Eating poison is bad = To eat poison is bad.

Answer (score 0):

'Gerund' (to carry on) and 'gerundive' (to be performed) are terms from Latin.
They don't have a direct correspondence to English, but 'gerund' refers to the concept of an action, as opposed to a particular instance of that action.  In 'Sally was talking to her mom', 'was' gives the tense and 'talking' gives the action and its aspect.  This 'talking' is a verb under the subject 'Sally'.  In 'Talking to your mom is good', 'talking' is the subject and is a noun and therefore a gerund. In '... after talking to her mom', 'talking' is most likely a particular instance and not a general concept.  The same is true of the adverbial in: 'Sally, talking to her mom, started to cry'.  It is a matter of deciding whether the words "to be" can be inserted before the 'participle';  if so then it is a gerund.